# How to add JAR file in phpJasper Starter?

Tags: php, jasper-reports, jasperstarter

I am using jasper studio and phpjasper for reporting. I have added reference to external jar file in Jasper Studio for jasper reports and it is working as expected. Now i want to add that report in my code igniter project file (I am using PHP Jasper for running jasper reports). Now i want to reference my external JAR file to jasper also then only my report will work. How can i do that?

**I tried by putting the jar file into the bin folder but didn't see it working.**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the .jar at the bin/jasperstarter/jdbc/ folder, according to the README there, "All jar files in this directory are added to the classpath."